After rotating the image, a black background appears instead of a transparent background, which prevents these images from being overlaid normally
I wrote a Python program with Pillow to overlay a bunch of small images onto one large one. There was an adequate overlay, in which the transparent color did not replace the previous superimposed images. But I had to rotate the images -15..15 degrees. And after the rotation, the overlay began to overlap the previous images. What's the problem
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
import numpy as np
path_to_small_image = "myaw.png"
small_image = Image.open(path_to_small_image)
mnoj = 4
small_image = small_image.resize((int(small_image.width / mnoj), int(small_image.height / mnoj)))
small_image = small_image.convert('P')
#small_image = small_image.filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(1))


width, height = 1920 + small_image.width*2, 1080 + small_image.height*2
background_color = (255, 255, 255)


background = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))

num_images = 5000
x_coords = np.random.randint(0, width, size = [num_images])
y_coords = np.random.randint(0, height, size = [num_images])

small_image = small_image.convert('RGBA')
for i in range(len(x_coords)):
    x = x_coords[i]
    y = y_coords[i]
    si = small_image.rotate(np.random.randint(-15, 15))
    background.paste(si, (x,y), small_image.convert('RGBA'))

background = background.crop((small_image.width, small_image.width, 1920+small_image.width, 1080+small_image.width))
background.save('output.png')
background.show()

in the photo, what do I fill in and what happens


I looked at some old themes, but I saw that it seemed to be an old mistake that had already been fixed (it was related to resize, not rotate)
